# Problem I am facing using the len command and while loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I have this block of code, which is supposed to figure out how many letters there are in the input. If it is greater than 1 or less than 1(no input), there is an error. However, when running this code, it still prints out "You entered an invalid..." even when I only input in a single letter, which shouldn't be passing through the while loop because its length is only 1. Idk why this is happening any *beginner friendly* help is appreciated!

```
letter_guess = input("Enter a single letter to guess: ")
length = len(letter_guess)
while length > 1 or length < 1:
    letter_guess = input("You entered an invalid amount of letters, please guess again: ")
```

Comment: At the second `input()` you update `letter_guess`, but not `length`. Did you mean to add: `length = len(letter_guess)` as the last line?

Comment: @quamrana Yikes, silly me, thanks so much for pointing that out!

Comment: `length > 1 or length < 1` is long for `length != 1`.

Answer (score 0):

You should add `length = len(letter_guess)` in while loop after the input. As it's not updating currently.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to update the `length` variable again when you ask for the next guess.

```py
letter_guess = input("Enter a single letter to guess: ")
length = len(letter_guess)
while length > 1 or length < 1:
    letter_guess = input("You entered an invalid amount of letters, please guess again: ")
    length = len(letter_guess)
```